# How can I access a different `h` in `newtx` with the `ebgaramond` option?

Tags: newtx, ebgaramond

When I use the `newtx` package with the `ebgaramond` option, the letter `h` in math mode is very similar to `b`.  Is it possible to access an outbending `h` as I can see it documented in the `garamond-math` package?

[image: outbending h]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ebgaramond]{newtx}

\begin{document}
$hb,h^b,b^h$
 
\end{document}
```

[image: hb mix]

Comment: In order to use the character variant you need to go `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg, can I do that while still using the `newtx` package which is reasonably documented and  works extremely reliably?  I have zero experience with `unicode-math`.

Comment: Short answer: no.